# "without" at the end of a sentence

Tags: prepositions

> This is something you can't get around without.

Is the final word here ok? I believe it is as valid as "with" at the end of a sentence. But haven't found confirmation yet.

Comment: Is there a reason why you think that although "with" works in that position, "without" might not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's fine. This is a common result of joining two clauses with a relative pronoun. Let's break the process down.

The deep structure is roughly:

> This is something. You can't get around without **it**.

Next step, we replace "it" with the relative pronoun "that".

> This is something. You can't get around without **that**.

Then we *front* the relative pronoun, leaving a blank space behind, and join the two sentences together:

> This is something **that** you can't get around without ________.

This sentence is fine as it is, but English allows us to optionally remove the relative pronoun:

> This is something _______ you can't get around without ________.

And we're done!

Some people insist there's a rule that says you cannot end a sentence with a preposition, but there's actually no such rule.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "without" can work at the end of a sentence:

> This is something you can't get around without.

and does at the end of the example. Whether it works depends on the sentence, of course.

Comment: I think it can be written as —This is something without which you can't get around, am i correct?

Comment: @Sam  It could be, yes. But  I am not sure that is a large improvement. The original is fine, in my view.

Comment: @Araucaria -Thanks. Error now fixed.